# How can I extract all the speech sections (as an audio file) from a videos?

Tags: audio

I have several videos from movies,  which contain sections where the characters are talking with other types of sections (background music only, sound effects,  etc.). I'd like to extract the speech sections only. I'd like avoid finding the sections myself manually.

How can I extract all the speech sections (as an audio file, not a transcription using speech-to-text) from a video?